# Web API: Chrome Network tab reports huge request processing time, but the request finishes in milliseconds

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm working on some performance issues on an ASP.NET / Angular website, and I noticed something quite interesting in Google Chrome that I can't understand.

The time it takes the .NET Web Api to finish the request takes a few milliseconds, but Google Chrome reports it taking a few *seconds*.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate what I mean:
[image: Screenshot with highlighted request that took 2,59 seconds to complete]
As you can see the request took 2,59 seconds to complete.

If I take out this request and do it solo (right clicking and selecting 'Open in new Tab', I get a completely different result, like seen here:

[image]

This time, the request took 81 ms, which is a huge difference from the 2,59 seconds reported in the first screenshot.

Debugging the app has shown me that there's nothing special going on in this request. It simply returns a list. The query that does this is FAST. I can also run this request 100x and it remains fast, yet in the app it seems to be slow.

I'm at a loss at what could be going on.

I have investigated the following:

1. I thought my web api was handling the requests coming in one by one, first finishing the first request and then moving on to the second one. I have tested this by putting breakpoints on both web api methods and they are fired at the same time and complete intermittently.
2. I thought it may be due to the first request in Entity Framework being slow and afterwards being fast. It's not, because if I load the page a first time, and then a second time, I see the exact same results.

The request is done with Angular, like so:

```
return $http.get(service.url + '/organisationsorts').success(function(data)
       { //data is processed here });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to further look at this? What things I can try?

The technologies used are:

1. .NET Web Api
2. Entity Framework
3. Angular JS to do the request

An example of the Web Api Request:

```
    [Route("organisationsorts")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IList<SortOrganizationListDto> GetAllOrganisationSorts()
    {
        return _service.GetAllOrganisationSorts();
    }
```

And the corresponding implementation:

```
    public IList<SortOrganizationListDto> GetAllOrganisationSorts()
    {
        try
        {
            return Uow.GetStandardRepo<SortOrganisation>().GetAll().OrderBy(x => x.Name).Project().To<SortOrganizationListDto>().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("GetAllOrganisationSorts has failed", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This selects 5 rows from the table using Entity Framework and projecting it via AutoMapper to a ListDto.

Comment: can you share your WebApi methods and if you are using Tasks check ConfigureAwait

Comment: If you see it in Firefox, do you have the same behavior? I would also open Fiddler, to see how the request is recorded there.

Comment: In Firefox, I see the same behavior. About two seconds to load up the request in the page, about 100 milliseconds to repeat the same request. Will try Fiddler

Comment: Also added the Web API method

Comment: Fiddler shows me the same behavior. The request takes about 2 seconds when loading the page. If I repeat just one of the API calls, it is immensely fast (< 200 milliseconds). 
So it would seem like the requests being fired at the API are somehow stalled for some reason. Is there any way to debug this?